# Redis spop returns null despite key being present - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have this issue where the `spop` Redis command is returning `null` despite one key/entry being present in the database.

I never came across this issue on the Redis server running on my local machine. The annoying thing is that there is no error or anything.

I use Redis Desktop Manager to check what is inside the Heroku Redis database.

This is the NodeJS code that grabs the value in the database:

```
redis.spop('id', function (err, result) {}
```

One thing that I might do out of the ordinary is as follow: I have up to 6 processes `popping` values from the database at the same time.

Any idea what could cause this strange behavior?

## Tech specs:

- Redis local: 3.0.4
- Redis remote: Heroku 3.0.3
- NodeJS module: ioredis

Comment: Are you checking if `err` is defined?

Comment: Yes, as explained in the original questions, there are no error to be found. Nor the app crashes nor nothing.

Comment: If you have 6 processing popping values from the database, how do you know there's still (at least) one left?

Comment: There is a timer that i set very time there is nothing more in the database that fires the method to do a check if there is something still in the database. And another thing, the command `glen` to sound how many elements are in the table sees that there is stuff in it.

Comment: But if you have multiple readers, how do you know that in between determining the size of your set and actually popping a value off there wasn't another reader that popped it already?

Comment: I don't care if there is something or not. if popping returns something, i process it, if not i idle with a timer. 

Plus popping reads and removes the element at the same time. So there is no way that two workers will read the same value, and even if, in my case that is not an issue. But I hope that Redis developers made it right ;)

Comment: Does the issue occur when you only have one reader? Because I doubt that in a normal situation you'd get back a `null` (meaning the set is empty) when there's actually still items in the set, and it sounds to me like there's a race condition in between checking the set size and popping a value off it.

Comment: @robertklep you are right, having multiple threads is the issue here. Could you explain why is that? Is it that Redis can't handle two operations trying to delete a record to well? And what is actually happening, because I can't pop, but I can count how many elements are inside, and I can see all the entries from a Desktop Manager for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that something like this is happening:

- Reader #1 checks to see if there's data left in the set
- Redis returns *"yes, I have one item left"*
- Reader #2 checks to see if there's data left in the set
- Redis returns *"yes, I have one item left"*
- Reader #1 pops this item (emptying the set)
- Reader #2 tries to pop the item, and gets back a `null` because the set is now empty.

There is a race condition between checking the set size and popping a value, which means that there's a small time window in between those two operations that another reader can also pop a value (that's why this issue doesn't happen when you only have one reader).

Redis has some commands for *lists* (like [`BRPOP`](http://redis.io/commands/brpop)) that wait until there's an actual item to pop, but there isn't anything similar for *sets*. However, the Redis documentation contains [some example code](http://redis.io/commands/BLPOP#pattern-event-notification) on how you might be able to implement something like it.

Alternatively, you could implement some form of locking, although that would probably have a performance impact.

In the end, perhaps it's not even a big issue if your readers pop from an empty set, in which case they would just ignore the `null` and check again later.