# Redis set becomes empty

Tags: redis

I have a list of 10 million unique items in Redis set. When the set gets populated then I run 4 independent workers which use the SPOP (get&remove) command. Each worker processes 6 items every 20 seconds (the API limits I deal with). Redis runs with pretty much default config, but the appendonly is set to "yes".

The problem is that after ~20k items are processed the Redis set becomes empty and the workers are jobless. Why is that? There's no TTL on keys and by default Redis should keep them forever. The appendonly.aof file still remains huge on disk.

I run Redis 3.0.7 on Debian 8, no errors in Redis.

Comment: Bit too generic, you should post some code ;)

Comment: There's probably race condition as described in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34337030/5691697